# Approve/TransferFrom Methods

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens

During an Audit I got a warning for this code lines:

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
    // recommends that there are no checks for the approval double-spend attack
    // as this should be implemented in user interfaces

```
function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
    return true;
```

But the audit says I should use this below:

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
```

After reading the ECR-20 API it says this is a solution:

```
function approve(
  address _spender,
  uint256 _currentValue,
  uint256 _value)
returns (bool success)
```

What is the difference between the first 2?
Is this just a difference in Solidity langauge 4.5 vs. 5.0?

I noticed the EIP says that these issues should be handled by the interfece vs an actual check code.

Your thoughts?

Comment: The first one is compatible with solc v0.4.21 or higher (due to the usage of `emit` before event name). The second one is compatible with solc v0.4.20 or lower (due to the lack of `emit` before event name). The third one is not even a standard ERC20 function (though it will compile under any version of solc). Note that all versions start with '0' (and not '4' or '5' as you've mentioned).

Comment: You should ask the auditor to provide a detailed reasoning for the requested change. IMHO you should use `emit` and do not rely on old compilers with known bugs.